# Can Arduino and App Inventor 2 apps communicate two ways?

Tags: arduino, app-inventor

I'm wondering whether it's possible to write code for the Arduino that will store a led or a switch state and when an app from App Inventor 2 sends a request asking what state they are in the app gets an answer.

I can't find any information on the subject. I would appreciate it if someone had a good guide, video or some information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There are blocks for Send and Receive serial data over bluetooth.

Comment: More info would be more helpful!